# using this.addClass (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying this.addclass in jquery to add a class to a DIV, that could be unknown. Can this be solved in this way?

```
<style>.classOne { font-size:24px; color:#009900;}</style>

<script>
function hello()
{   alert();
$(this).addClass('classOne');
}
</script>

<div class="something"  onclick="hello();"> Test information </div>
```

Comment: [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/) A great place to test stuff before asking questions ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Avoid inline javascript whenever you can, and do something like this instead :

```
<style>.classOne { font-size:24px; color:#009900;}</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.something').on('click', function() {
        alert('hello');
        $(this).addClass('classOne');
    });
});
</script>

<div class="something"> Test information </div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/H7Eqq/)

Comment: I think- I can't tell exactly, that he wants to add this function to many divs besides just '.somthing'

Comment: "Avoid inline javascript whenever you can", why? inline been around forever, its faster and often easier to debug. i use as much inline as possible as opposed to having 50,000 lines of code to filter through. You're the second person i've seen say that and i still dont see why. maybe i'm just to old school for you young whipper snappers, lol. More lines of code = more crap to read = longer to process for both me and the PC

Comment: Not too mention, one of jQuery's key features, "chaining", is designed specifically for "inline" coding. Why would you recommend against this?, OH NM! I just got what you ment, i was thinking inline in the code, not on the element, *facepalm* stupie moment!

Comment: You got it! By inline JS I meant inline in the HTML, i.e. using onmouseover, onclick etc. in the HTML. There's nothing really wrong with it, but these days seperating function, apperance and layout makes things a lot easier, and having javascript and styles in seperate files is almost always the way to go. Chaining on the other hand is of course just fine, and is one of the core features in any javascript library.

Comment: The correct answer for this should be Riaan Walters answer below.

Comment: @mateostabio - no it shouldn't ;.)

Answer (score 8):

Your reference to "this" is invalid, try this instead

```
<style>.classOne { font-size:24px; color:#009900;}</style>

<script>
function hello(ojecttRef)
{   
     alert();
     $(ojecttRef).addClass('classOne');
}
</script>

<div class="something"  onclick="hello(this);"> Test information </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be better...

```
//Bind a click event to the div
$('div').on('click', function(){
     $(this).addClass('classOne');
});

//No Onclick needed here
<div class="something"> Stuff Here </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('this').addClass('classOne');` instead.

`this` cannot go alone itself. Need to be in `$()`